# Aliasing Font Awesome Class

Tags: css, fonts, extjs4, font-awesome

How do I properly Alisas a font awesome class such as `fa fa-users` to `user` ?

I am developing an Ext application, and I need to use font awesome icons, the following works for me:

```
<i class="fa fa-users"></i>
```

However the icon to use is database result driven, hence I wish to use an alias class for `fa fa-users`, then I can switch classes dynamically. How do I do this.

Already tried:

**Method 1**

CSS:

```
.user
{
font-family: FontAwesome;
   content: "\f095";
}
```

**Method 2**

Jquery Approach to alias class

```
$document.ready(function(){
$('.users').addClass('fa fa-users');
}):
```

In both cases using as:

```
<i class="user></i>
```

But no icon appears, I just cant figure out what I am missing.

Comment: Why? If you control the code that sets up the class, why not have a mapping table where you map "user" from the db to "fa fa-users" for your UI? All you need is a plain object `{ user: "fa fa-users", ...}`.

Comment: That's my last resort , but doesn't feel right to specify css classes in an sql query. Would require frequent query changes. I myself am new to professional codding so am not sure of that approach

Comment: that's not what I'm saying. Do your SQL query, and when you get the result back, you transform it from "data received from the database" to "markup used in the browser". You don't make your database generate HTML, that would be really weird.

Comment: Ya that's how I have presently done it.  But was looking for a UI solution for UI issue.

Answer (score 3):

you have to `addClass` to `i` instead

```js
$('.users i').addClass('fa fa-users');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.2/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="users">
  <i></i> 
</div>
```

Comment: Please provide a link to your site